# how to display categoreis from different stores under same navingation in magento

Tags: php, magento

i am new to magento , I have 2 stores with different Root categories, what i want to know is how to display categories from both store under same Navigation Bar,  I mean i want some thing like

```
   Nav Bar----> Cat1(Store1)|Cat2(Store1)| Cat3(Store2)|Cat4(Store2).
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just load your category by id, like this,

```
<?php
       
    echo Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(5)->getUrl();
?>
```

5 -> is your category id. Its unique. So no problem by different store.

**Update :**

First you need to know where it would coming from (which file ).? For this enable **template path hints** in your admin panel. Just google how to do this..So now you know the file and thats path. Then modify it, its like this, (just example)

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you dont want previous links just remove and add like this,

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(5)->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(5)->getName(); ?></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: i dont know where to load it can yu tell me where to load this?Also, will this solution append categories to my nav bar?